# Computer bumpers/feet have fallen off of my Razer Blade 14. How do I fix it?

Tags: laptop, case

The bottom of my computer (Razer Blade 14) has these small rubber bumpers. Today the back one fell off.

If someone could tell me a way to fix it or point me in that direction it would be great.

Comment: super blue them back on

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Short answer:** Glue it back on with silicone adhesive.

**Long answer:**

- **Metal Cases**

  The Raser Blade 14 manufacturer's web site seems to indicate that the case is aluminum.  Super glue isn't the best adhesive for gluing feet to metal cases.  Regular super glue is brittle, doesn't work well with flexible materials, and has low sheer strength.  I've had some super-glued feet knocked off when moving the computers around.   Silicone adhesive is better.
- **Plastic Cases**

  A number of different plastics are used for laptop cases (ABS and polycarbonate are common), so the best adhesive, and results, may vary.

  Certain types of super glue will bond well to some types of plastic.  However, it reacts with some types of plastic, which can be damaged and even etched by the fumes.  There are safer adhesives for these cases.

  Many silicone adhesives bond well to the common case plastics (Dow Corning 739 Plastic Adhesive is specifically designed for plastics, but many others also work well, check the label).  Another is JB Weld PlasticWeld.

**General Tips**

If you use the type of silicone adhesive that has a vinegar odor, that relies on moisture to cure.  Breathe on both surfaces to leave a little humidity right before you apply the adhesive and before pressing the parts together.  That will help speed up curing.  Let the adhesive cure for a good day before stressing it (moving the computer by sliding it on the feet).

Whatever adhesive you use, it is important to start with very clean surfaces.  Remove any old adhesive and clean the surfaces well with 90% or higher isopropyl alcohol.

**Concealed Screws**

On laptop cases, the feet sometimes conceal screws that may someday need to be accessed.  If so, it might be better to stick the feet on in a way that can be removed if necessary.  The manufacturers typically use double-sided sticky tape (which is why the feet sometimes pull off).  "Industrial strength" double-sided or mounting tapes will hold similar to the original. Silicone can be cut and scraped away if necessary.  JB Weld may require damaging the case if you ever need to get the screws out.

**If You Lose a Foot**

Losing a foot isn't the end of the world.  You can mold a new one with [Sugru](https://sugru.com/about) or [Oogoo](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Make-Your-Own-Sugru-Substitute/?ALLSTEPS).

Answer (score 4):

I repair laptops for a living and I have reattached rubber laptop feet many times.

I always use super glue. Just apply enough to cover the entire contact surface of the rubber and stick it on, press firmly on it for 30 seconds so the glue can set. Let it sit on a table and dry all the way for at least 4 hours, that way the laptop will apply pressure to the feet. For best results, let the laptop sit for 24 hours or more.

You might want to lightly scratch both surfaces with a sharp knife to help it adhere better. Also, super glue that specifically says it bonds to plastic and rubber might work better, although I have never needed to use a "special" kind.

Pulling or flexing the rubber and purposely trying to remove the feet does not work without prying with a flat-head screwdriver.

@fixer1234 has a great point, cleaning both surfaces with 90% isopropyl alcohol and removing any old adhesive will ensure optimal bond strength.

I have never required the use of a flexible glue. None of my customers have had problems, and my personal laptops that required this repair still have their feet firmly attached. The area of rubber that contacts the laptop does not flex very much.

I doubt that silicon adhesive will adhere to a smooth plastic surface and a smooth rubber surface as well as super glue. Even on rough surfaces super glue will likely adhere better.

Comment: Sometimes computer feet are used to cover screws, in which case a less permanent adhesive would be better.

Comment: They come right off with a flathead if needed, at least in my experience.

Comment: `Super Glue` is worst advice I have ever seen. It leaves irremovable white stains on plastic and it's connection is inflexible, which means that would not last long. You need some glue which makes flexible joints like: Neoprene glue or silicon glue proposed by @fixer1234

Comment: @Virus_7 It lasts year after year without a problem, and "white spots" are nowhere to be seen. Flexible glue is not required.

Comment: @fixer1234 The scratches are filled by the glue and when it dries you have a solid piece of glue with "anchors" in both surfaces. In my testing, the bond strength is increased.